# An internal error occurred while calling 'saveDocumentToCorporateMDP' API. (Error: ERR_WIS_30270)

Tags: business-objects

I have an instance of a (very detailed) report in SAP BO WebI that from time to time fails to be ran, with this error:

> An internal error occurred while calling 'saveDocumentToCorporateMDP' API. (Error: ERR_WIS_30270)

I suspect it could be a problem regarding the memory of the BO server but I don't know how to fix it without installing more MBs.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
I couldn't find any suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I solved it raising the value of `Maximum Binary Stream` on LCM configuration from 800 MB to 1 GB.

Answer (score 0):

If its a memory issue, the report may run for a while and then fail. Do you see the report duration (start time minus end time) to be longer? Do you have access to the Instance Manager in the Management Console?

Comment: Yes it starts, runs for a while and then fails. I don't have access to the Management Console.